# Coding System utf-8 on Mac - Which one and why as default?

Tags: init-file, character-encoding, unicode

I want to change my default encoding system from non defined to UTF-8 (I think that would be useful). Now I have seen many different UTF-8 coding systems:

```
mule-utf-8        mule-utf-8-dos
mule-utf-8-mac    mule-utf-8-unix
prefer-utf-8      prefer-utf-8-dos
prefer-utf-8-mac  prefer-utf-8-unix
utf-8             utf-8-auto
utf-8-auto-dos    utf-8-auto-mac
utf-8-auto-unix   utf-8-dos
utf-8-emacs       utf-8-emacs-dos
utf-8-emacs-mac   utf-8-emacs-unix
utf-8-hfs         utf-8-hfs-dos
utf-8-hfs-mac     utf-8-hfs-unix
utf-8-mac         utf-8-unix
utf-8-with-signature     utf-8-with-signature-dos
utf-8-with-signature-mac utf-8-with-signature-unix
```

I am using a Mac and I am further confused about these different hfs and mac coding systems.

At the moment I decided to use utf-8 as follow based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2903256/632423):

```
(setq utf-translate-cjk-mode nil) ; disable CJK coding/encoding (Chinese/Japanese/Korean characters)
(set-language-environment 'utf-8)
;; (set-keyboard-coding-system 'utf-8-mac) ; For old Carbon emacs on OS X only
(setq locale-coding-system 'utf-8)
(set-default-coding-systems 'utf-8)
(set-terminal-coding-system 'utf-8)
(unless (eq system-type 'windows-nt)
  (set-selection-coding-system 'utf-8))
(prefer-coding-system 'utf-8)
```

But I would like to understand some more what I am doing and why another utf-8 would be better as a default coding system?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17864979/605276) provides good background on different utf-8 variants.

Comment: I don't see `utf-8-hfs` and friends on my emacs, but there is `utf-8-nfd` instead. That is the encoding used by OS X to encode filenames. NFD is for Normalized Form Canonical Decomposition. NFC is more commonly used (C is for Composition). One difference is that a letter like å is encoded as a single code point in NFC, but two in NFD (the letter a followed by a composing character for the ring above). You should probably forget about these encodings; just hope that filenames are automagically encoded correctly anyhow.

Comment: @Juancho Thanks - so I assume that, that I am OK when I use the utf-8 as a general setting. Thanks.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen OK - As I am only using ASCII for file names, I should be OK then. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I try stick to ASCII for filenames myself, as I live in a multi-OS world and rely on all sorts of synchronization tools that I don't trust to deal with anything else. But it is annoying not to be able to use `blåbærsyltetøy` as part of a filename. 8-)

Comment: AFAIK, utf-8 is the coding system used under macos for most things, and Emacs should already pick its coding systems accordingly for you.  IOW, I think you should need *no configuration at all*.  Please clarify why you "want to change my default encoding system".  Maybe you're simply hitting an Emacs bug.

Comment: Back when Macs used MacOS (which was before they used OSX which was before they used MacOS; yay naming), the end-of-line syntax on Macs was a single carriage return.  That's what the `-mac` suffix'd coding system variants are for (ever since those days).  Nowadays, since Macs started using OSX and subsequently MacOS (yay naming) the EOL syntax is (I believe) a single line feed, which is the `-unix` suffix/variant.  I imagine the "will pick the correct variant" advice is sound, though.

Answer (score 0):

Emacs has `[Menu]->[Options]->[Multilingual Environment]->[Describe Coding System...]` or `C-h C` to explain the difference and disambiguate the different coding systems.